# Separate data items into lists by DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

Given class

```cs
public class SomeType
{
    public string Name;
    public string Field2;
    public DateTime CreatedOnDateTime
}
```

I want to take a `List<SomeType>` and divide it into several `List<SomeType>` where each List contains items with an equal CreatedOnDateTime stamp.  In many cases CreatedOnDateTime will be the same, it would be nice to allow a tolerance of a couple seconds.

I could run a LINQ query N number of times to create each distinct list.  Is there a more efficient mechanism? In other words, can this type of query be built with LINQ using some type of grouping mechanism?  (when I say grouping I am imagining a RegEx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you use a regex? That's for textual pattern matching. It sounds like you want [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx):

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.CreatedOnDateTime);

foreach (var entry in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Created: {0}", entry.Key);
    foreach (var item in entry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}, {1}", item.Name, item.Field2);
    }
}
```

Note that that will go for *identical* timestamps. Creating a "tolerance" as such is difficult, but you could effectively "round down" the entries to a couple of seconds:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => RoundDownToTwoSeconds(x.CreatedOnDateTime));

...

private static DateTime RoundDownToTwoSeconds(DateTime input)
{
    return new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, input.Hour,
                        input.Minute, (input.Second / 2) * 2,
                        input.Kind);
}
```

(Think of a better name if you want :)

The reason simple "tolerance" is hard is this situation:

```
Entry 1: 12:05:14
Entry 2: 12:05:15
Entry 3: 12:05:16
Entry 4: 12:05:17
```

Entries 1 and 2 are only a second apart... so they should go in the same bucket. But entries 2 and 3 are only a second apart... so they should go in the same bucket too. Entries 3 and 4 are only a second apart, so entry 4 should go in the same bucket as well. Now we've got entries 1 and 4, three seconds apart, in the same bucket.

Comment: I had to add a reference to `System.Data.Entity` to get this working.  Although in visual studio the error highlighted `ILookup`, which is part of the `System.Data` assem, the real problem was in a dependency on ComplexObject which is in `System.Data.Entity` assem.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: You *definitely* don't need a reference to `System.Data.Entity` for the code you've given. You should have a using directive for `System.Linq`, and a reference to `System.Core`. Of course, if your *actual* code refers to something in System.Data.Entity, then that's another matter - but nothing you've *shown* requires that.

Comment: Once again you are correct.  I had not realized that one of my own classes returned an Entity Framework object.

Comment: I noticed that you and plenty of other devs use `var` when returning items from LINQ queries.  Doesn't this conflict with the recommended usage of var?  In other words, it shouldn't be used here because the return type is not clear.  So why is it so commonly used for LINQ?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Well it *has* to be used when there are anonymous types of course... but here it feels clear enough, and more readable than `ILookup<DateTime, SomeType>` IMO.

Comment: FWIW, I recently learned about the 3 major return types that LINQ offers:  IEnumerable<>, IQueryable<> and Anonymous Types.  My lack of understanding of the Anon Types made the LINQ return values quite magical.  Now that I have this understanding along with a comprehension of Func<> and Action<> reading and writing LINQ and using var makes a lot more sense.  For anyone in the same boat, I recommend Pluralsight's LINQ fundamentals training course.

Answer (score 0):

For the tolerance bit (assuming you're using a toLookup/groupBy) you can group on (datetime.ticks / toloranceInTicks).  You could probably use TotalMilliseconds and a tolorance in MS too if you prefer.  It may or may not handle edge cases the way that you want, but if your data tends to not have many edge cases it should work.  This will work well if the difference in time between times that ought to be grouped together is significantly larger than times that should not be grouped together.  If that statement holds then you can choose a tolerance somewhere between those two differences and you'll be fine.  If, however, your times are rather continuous and the two differences are not far apart then the odds of your tolerance being too small or too large grow a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
int precison = 2; //in sec.
var groups = list.GroupBy(s => s.CreatedOnDateTime.Ticks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 1000 * precison))
                 .Select(x => new List<SomeType>(x) )
                 .ToList();
```

`groups` will be a list of `List<SomeType>`